# How can I make fade out text

Tags: html, css

This is my first question on this platform.
I am trying to make anki card that shows a question for a number of seconds then I need it to fade out.

this is the code that I have found.

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
100%,0%{opacity:.5;}
0%,0%{opacity:1;}
}
.fade-out {
font-size:20px;
color: dodgerblue;
background:white; 
padding:10px;
opacity:0;
-webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1; 
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-webkit-animation-duration:2s;
-webkit-animation-delay:4s;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of stuff is usually easy to just google, but anyways this is a solution that will work perfectly

```css
.fader {
  animation: fadeOut ease 8s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut ease 8s;
  -moz-animation: fadeOut ease 8s;
  -o-animation: fadeOut ease 8s;
  -ms-animation: fadeOut ease 8s;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

```html
<h1 class="fader">
  Hey!
</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you so much . How can I make it faster and without a loop, because I am using in anki card ?

Comment: @MAZIN It's not actually looping, that's just how snippets work. To make it faster just edit the 8s in the .fader{} to how many ever seconds you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an animation with the @keyframes tag. For instance

```
@keyframes fade-out {
  100%{
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}
```

and then also in your CSS you have something like this:

```
.your-class{
  animation: fade-out 3s linear 10s 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

And then in your HTML you have this:

```
<div class="your-class">What is 1+1?</div>
```

The values in the CSS mean that the "fade-out" animation will be played in a 3s time and a linear animation. The 10s mean that after 10s the animation will play, so it means that the card will disappear after 10s. and the "1" means it will only play 1 time, this is optional since 1 is the default value.
animation-fill-mode means that the value that's in the animation (opacity: 0%) will remain and only goes away when you refresh the page for instance. It will overtake the default value which is normally 100%;

Hoped this helped you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. but it does not work, please, How can I make it faster and without loop?

Comment: do you mean the animation? or the time that the animation will play?

Comment: Yes, I need it to run one time in fade out action.